# Howto connect to a VPN, which is already setup in an Android phone, programmatically

Tags: android, vpn

I have configured a VPN connection in my Android phone. Now I would like to connect this VPN via a widget. How can I initiate a connection programmatically? Most code assumes there is no VPN setup yet, but this is not where I am looking for. I look especially for code which connects to an already configured VPN.

On http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8915 I have found this code:

```
VpnService service = context.getSystemService(VPN_SERVICE);
VpnProfile profile = VpnProfile.create(L2TP_PROFILE);
profile.setName(myServerName);
profile.setServerName(myServerAddress);
profile.setRouteList(“192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0,192.168.10.0/255.255.255.0”);

service.connect(profile, myUserName, myPassword);
service.setNotificationIntent(myIntent);
```

Which configures a new VPN. I want just to connect an existing VPN.

This page http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html describes how to implement your own VPN service, which is also not what I am looking for.

Comment: Please post some code and better explain what you have tried.

Comment: I do not have any code yet which is exactly the problem. I am looking for example code on how to connect and existing VPN.

Comment: The example you posted is just a "what I would like to have" example from the link you posted.

Comment: If you like I can show you how this can be done in 2.2 and 2.3 very easily. I have a working example and I myself is now looking for a way to do the same on 4.x.

Comment: slott, please explain how to do this in 2.2 and 2.3. My email: anivaler@tut.by. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to do that by using l2tp?

Answer (score 1):

Here the example of using VpnService https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn

Comment: Does it support l2tp?